# Unable to remove tag of a docker image due to 'no such image' error

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

Here is a output from my `docker images` command

```
REPOSITORY                                                      TAG                    IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
888668560264.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/simplequeue   0.1                    df74fbea0533        11 minutes ago      601 MB
888668560264.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/simplequeue   0.2                    df74fbea0533        11 minutes ago      601 MB
888668560264.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/simplequeue   latest                 df74fbea0533        11 minutes ago      601 MB
```

These images have been pushed to aws ecr.

I have mistagged the image as 0.1 and I want to remove this label. However, when I tried `docker rmi`

```
> docker rmi simplequeue:0.1
Error response from daemon: No such image: simplequeue:0.1
```

If I just use `docker rmi simplequeue`, I got this

```
> docker rmi simplequeue
Untagged: simplequeue:latest
```

and the docker images output stay the same. It does not look to me the tags have been removed (`latest` and `0.1` are still avaialble).

How can I remove the tag `0.1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, you have to specify repository + tag.

`docker rmi 888668560264.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/simplequeue:0.1`

Answer (score 0):

I think If you use the -f flag and specify the image’s short or long ID, then this command untags and removes all images that match the specified ID.
`docker rmi -f zzzzz:xx`

Comment: I used `docker rmi -f df74fbea0533:0.1 ` and I get `Error response from daemon: No such image: df74fbea0533:0.1`